# Unable to delete an object in InDesign, bug?

Tags: adobe-indesign, mac

How can I delete an object that I can select and move around, but can't delete via keyboard `delete` button nor cut via the right click `cut` option?

This is on MacOs.

It feels like a bug...

Comment: Sounds strange. Does the problem persist even if you save and restart InDesign? Isn't there anything out of the ordinary with that object? Anchored in a text frame perhaps? Check how it looks in the Layers panel. It would be easier to help, if you could show some screenshots or a gif.

Comment: It's not a "bug".. it's some local problem for you... try some simple trouble shooting.. restart InDesign, restart the computer. This is tech support and of topic here.